# Rust does not live long enough

Tags: rust

есть структура `Scene` в ней хранятся объекты и ресурсы к ним. сами объекты и ресурсы создаются в методе `load`. дело в том что появилась ошибка:

> error[E0597]: `scene` does not live long enough
>
> 62 |     scene.load(load);
>
> ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
>
> `scene` dropped here while still borrowed. borrow might be used here, when `scene` is dropped and runs the destructor for type `Scene<'_>`

если я правильно понял. имеется в виду что `scene` остаётся внутри метода. вопрос в этом ли проблема и как её исправить. вот проблемный кусок кода.

```
trait Controller{
    fn update(&mut self,data: &mut ObjectData);
}

struct ObjectData<'a>{
    resources: &'a Vec<Box<Any>>,
    renderer: Rc<Renderer + 'a> ,
    scene_event: Sender<fn(&mut Scene)>
}

struct Object<'a>{
    data: ObjectData<'a>,
    controller: Option<Box<Controller>>
}

struct Scene<'a>{
    objects: Vec<Object<'a>>,
    rx: Receiver<fn(&mut Scene)>,
    tx: Sender<fn(&mut Scene)>,
    resources: Vec<Box<Any>>
}


impl<'a> Scene<'a> {
    fn new() -> Scene<'a>{
        let (tx,rx):(Sender<fn(&mut Scene)>,Receiver<fn(&mut Scene)>)= mpsc::channel();
        let scene = Scene{ objects: Vec::new(),rx,tx,resources: Vec::new()};
        scene
    }

    fn load(&'a mut self, loader: fn(scene: &'a mut Scene<'a>)){
        loader(self);
    }

    fn push(&'a mut self,object: Object<'a>){
        self.objects.push(object);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut scene = Scene::new();
    scene.load(load);
}

fn load<'a>(scene: &'a mut Scene<'a>){

    let shader = Shader{id: 1};
    scene.resources.push(Box::new(shader));

    let render = SpriteRenderer{shader: scene.resources[0].downcast_ref().unwrap()};
    let data = ObjectData{
        resources: &scene.resources,
        scene_event: scene.tx.clone(),
        renderer:Rc::new(render)};
    let object = Object{ data,controller: None};
    scene.objects.push(object);
}


pub trait Renderer {
   fn draw(&self);
}

pub struct SpriteRenderer<'a>{
   pub shader: &'a Shader
}

impl<'a> Renderer for SpriteRenderer<'a> {
     fn draw(&self) {}
}

pub struct Shader {
   pub id:u32
}
```

Comment: Я не супер знаток, но что если перенести функцию `load`, которая содержит `&mut self` в `impl` блок?

Comment: так и есть. просто решил не писать в вопросе много кода. дополнил

Comment: Мне кажется дело в том, что вы передаете `load`, который не относится к структуре не по референсу. После исполнения `loader(self)` он дропается, утягивая за собой `self`, что, считайте, равно `scene`

Comment: @chabapok привёл код полностью

Comment: @chabapok, тут проблема не в циклических ссылках, а в том что в Rust мутабельные ссылки работают не очень очевидным образом. Если коротко, то ссылки вида `&'a mut T<'a>` - это антипаттерн. Решение в том чтобы разделить времена жизни. 

Вот рабочий код упрощенного примера: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=173693d07408b61d327e2340589c9250

Вот ссылка на форум, где детально описывается эта проблема: https://forum.rustycrate.ru/t/pochemu-peremennaya-data-zaimstvuetsya-posle-vyzova-funkczii/476

Comment: @aSpex, спасибо. Но с таким кодом не соберется потому, что  в теле функции есть самоссылающиеся поля. В минимальном примере этого нет, потому что я увлекся обрезанием и в спешке обрезал нужное. Если бы автор чуть лучше постарался и привел директивы `use` вначале кода и поубирал всякие сендеры-ресиверы которые к делу не имеют отношения - то это бы сфокусировало наше внимание на проблеме. На мой взгляд, тут нет проблем, на которые вы ссылаетесь. Гляньте это https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6aa9b7220c2d461cb5c7abc72f138032

Comment: @chabapok, да теперь вижу `ObjectData::resources` ссылается на `Scene::resources` . Сразу не посмотрел оригинальный код.

Comment: то есть чтобы исправить мне нужно `resources` или `objects` вытащить из `Scene`? или это не лучшее решение?

Comment: там ниже в сообщении я перечислил 4 варианта. Что лучше я не знаю. Я бы проработал возможность использования Pin, т.к. вроде бы это новое API как раз для таких целей предназначенное

Comment: @morpmorpovich это точно самое простое решение. Лучшее оно или нет зависит от того, как вы собираетесь использовать эти данные. Плюс (или минус :) ) Rust в том, что он заставляет тщательно продумывать архитектуру.

Comment: @chabapok а что в `Pin` оборачивать? если обернуть `resources` в `ObjectData` то ничего не меняется.

Comment: я забыл, как им пользоваться %(. Придется звать @aSpex

Comment: @chabapok я вроде разобрался. только вопрос обязательно использовать `NonNull`? потому что чтобы получить из него данные нужно использовать `unsafe` или без этого не как?

Comment: Вроде бы можно обойтись без ансейфа, но инфа не 100%. Я тут его покрутил и чуток вспомнил. Возможно, этот пример поможет https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23119ad351cc749ba0b99923a7ea446d Хотя скорей всего, если вы разобрались, то он уже не актуален. Наверное, на данный момент вы уже в этом лучше разбираетесь, чем я.

Comment: @chabapok пример который вы прислали. не отображает моей проблемы он должен выглядеть [как то так](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2097a0132ba8b9611c863ab04a5f239b)

Comment: Хм... Мне кажется, что наоборот - мой вариант ближе к вашему коду. В вашем примере вылезла ошибка заимствования, а не проблемы с лайфтаймами. Если в этом проблема (я сомневаюсь, что в этом - но вдруг) - вам повезло. Компиляцию легко продавить - это делается добавлением `Cell`, смотрите пример: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=84a8303a4d29d5a6a8fc606eca66f60f

Answer (score 1):

В минимально-воспроизводимом коде надо оставить только тот код, который относится к проблеме. И выглядеть тогда оно будет как-то так https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f9407e66279dae75c5d7dfa81e992f4b

И чем проще код - тем быстрей ответят.

Но вобщем суть в том, что поля структуры не могут ссылаться на другие поля этой же структуры. А у вас они так ссылаются. И чтобы компилятор это пропустил, вы добавили одинаковые лайфтаймы в метод `load`  и компилятор это пропустил. Но возникла проблема в другом месте - в месте удаления. Соответственно, если вы лайфтаймы поправите - то именно эту ошибку продавить получится - но будет ругаться где-то в теле метода `load`.

По сути, это проблема - это проблема циклических ссылок в раст. И пути ее решения такие же.

Там в последнем расте завели `Pin`для самоссылающихся полей. Можно, что-то на его основе сделать.

Можно еще туда городить `Rc+Weak` указатели. Но это куча.

И еще можно `unsafe`

И можно использовать арену. На арене создаются обьекты,а потом грохаются одновременно вместе с ареной.